# ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: pyinstaller failed to import module _pyinstaller_hooks_0_pandas_io_formats_style required for module

Tags: python, pandas, pyinstaller, hook, exe

I want to create an .exe file and get this error: Failed to import module _Pyinstaller_hooks_0_pandas_io_formats_style required for module C:xxxxxx\site-packages\Pyinstaller\hooks\hook-pandas.io.format.style.py.

I am not familiar with this subject at all and couldt find anything that could resolve the issue by using google. Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0):

This happened when freezing pandas inside `conda` environment using `pyinstaller`.

I had pandas installed using conda environment and also using pip like `pip install pandas`.

I removed the pip version and installed using **conda**, and that worked!

```sh
pip uninstall pandas
conda install -c conda-forge pandas
```