# PyInstaller PyQt5 hook error - failed to import module

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt, pyinstaller, exe

I'm trying to package a project using pyinstaller. It fails to create .exe. I have been going through the imports one by one and it seems that it is the Pandas import which fails because of a hook for pyqt5:

File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.py", line 12, in 
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks.qt import get_qt_binaries, pyqt5_library_info
ImportError: cannot import name 'get_qt_binaries' from 'PyInstaller.utils.hooks.qt' (C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\qt_*init*_.py)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\Scripts\pyinstaller-script.py", line 10, in 
sys.exit(run())
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main*_.py", line 179, in run
run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller_*main*_.py", line 60, in run_build
PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 963, in main
build(specfile, distpath, workpath, clean_build)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 885, in build
exec(code, spec_namespace)
File "H:\report_analysis\report_analysis\main.spec", line 7, in 
a = Analysis(
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 410, in **init**
self.**postinit**()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 173, in **postinit**
self.assemble()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 579, in assemble
self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks(self)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 329, in process_post_graph_hooks
module_hook.post_graph(analysis)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 447, in post_graph
self._load_hook_module(keep_module_ref=True)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 390, in _load_hook_module
raise ImportErrorWhenRunningHook(self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
PyInstaller.exceptions.ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: Failed to import module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_PyQt5 required by hook for module C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.py. Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_PyQt5 actually exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.py: You might want to read more about hooks in the manual and provide a pull-request to improve PyInstaller.

I'm not a Python programmer and inherited this project. I have no idea how to proceed. Is anyone familiar with this problem?

Based on other searches on this site/web I tried adding an additional hook:

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import qt_plugins_binaries
# Fixed the issue: could not find or load the Qt platform plugin "windows".
binaries = qt_plugins_binaries('platforms', 'PyQt5')
```

That also failed. I updated version of pyqt (now 5.9) reinstalled pyInstaller in my virtual environment. Exe is created fine up until I try running it with the Pandas import.

Updated Pandas based on this answer- [ImportErrorWhenRunningHook: pyinstaller failed to import module _pyinstaller_hooks_0_pandas_io_formats_style required for module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68791821/importerrorwhenrunninghook-pyinstaller-failed-to-import-module-pyinstaller-hoo)

But with no progress.

I run this with pyinstaller --onefile --debug=all main.py

Minimal Reproducible Example:

Main.py

```
import sys
import os

from gui import Window

def api():
    w = Window()
    w.window.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    api()
```

gui.py

```
"""This is the GUI object"""

from tkinter import Tk, Label, Button, Entry, filedialog, HORIZONTAL
from tkinter.ttk import Progressbar
from threading import Thread


from re import sub
from pandas import read_excel, DataFrame

class Window():
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = Tk()
        self.window.title('Report Analysis')
        self.window.geometry("480x640")
        self.window.config(background='white')
        self.widgets = []
        for text in ['Select a File', 'Sheet name', 'Select an Output Directory']:
            self.widgets.append(self.CreateLabel(text))
        self.widgets.insert(1, self.CreateButton('Browse Files', self.BrowseFiles))
        self.widgets.insert(3, Entry(self.window, bd=3, width=18))
        self.widgets.insert(5, self.CreateButton('Browse Directories', self.BrowseDirs))
        self.widgets.append(Label(self.window, text='', bg='white'))
        self.widgets.append(Button(self.window, text='Submit', command=self.Submit))
        for widget in self.widgets:
            index = self.widgets.index(widget)
            pady = ((index + 1) % 2 * 20, (index + 1) % 2 * 5)
            widget.grid(column=0, row=index, padx=50, pady=pady)
        self.progress = Progressbar(self.window, orient=HORIZONTAL, length=200, mode='indeterminate')
        
    def CreateLabel(self, text):
        return Label(self.window, text=text, width=50, height=2, fg='blue')
    
    def CreateButton(self, text, command):
        return Button(self.window, text=text, command=command, bd=3, width=18)
    
    def BrowseFiles(self):
        pass

    def BrowseDirs(self):
        pass

    def Submit(self):
        pass

    def ErrorHandling(self, import_file, sheet_name, output_path):
        if import_file == 'Select a File':
            raise Exception('No file selected.')
        if sheet_name.strip() == '':
            raise Exception('No sheet name entered.')
        if output_path == 'Select an Output Directory':
            raise Exception('No directory selected.')
```

Thanks in advance for your time

Comment: PS, "Please check whether module __PyInstaller_hooks_0_PyQt5 actually exists and whether the hook is compatible with your version of C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\clonebasic\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-PyQt5.py". The hook exists - I'm unsure how to test if it compatable.

Comment: Post a [mre], including the source, the spec file, command line, etc.

Comment: @relent95, thank you for your comment, I've added a reproducible example.

Comment: It seems either you are using an ancient version of PyInstaller or you corrupted your PyInstaller installation. Try with a new fresh installation of Python environment.